# Cassandra error Unable to connect to any servers', {'*': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('*', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-php-driver

Hello guys i need you help i am getting error in cassandra connection i.e connection refused

here is my cassandra.yaml file

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
credentials_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
    commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
cdc_enabled: false
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:

    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:


          - seeds: "10.84.36.89"
          concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 10.84.36.89
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 10.84.36.89
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
column_index_cache_size_in_kb: 2
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 500
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra

    client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false

    optional: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra

    internode_compression: dc
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
transparent_data_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    chunk_length_kb: 64
    cipher: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    key_alias: testing:1
    key_provider: 
      - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.security.JKSKeyProvider
        parameters: 
          - keystore: conf/.keystore
            keystore_password: cassandra
            store_type: JCEKS
            key_password: cassandra
            tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
replica_filtering_protection:

    cached_rows_warn_threshold: 2000
    cached_rows_fail_threshold: 32000
    batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
back_pressure_enabled: false
back_pressure_strategy:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure
      parameters:
        - high_ratio: 0.90
          factor: 5
          flow: FAST
          enable_materialized_views: true
enable_sasi_indexes: true
```

previously i was using localhost instead of 10.84.36.89 that time also not working.

i did not see any log file inside /var/log/cassandra also

i am using cqlsh 10.84.36.89 & 10.84.36.89 9042 for connecting cassandra, but both giving me same error

please help me to fix i am using ubuntu 18 & cassandra version 3.11, i can't update my cassandra version because new version is not supporting php driver

notetool status:

```
ERROR 16:21:09,536 Cannot initialize un-mmaper.  (Are you using a non-Oracle JVM?)  Compacted data files will not be removed promptly.  Consider using an Oracle JVM or using standard disk access mode
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'sun.misc.Cleaner sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner()'
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:75) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:880) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:216) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.execute(NodeTool.java:184) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:56) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getDiskFailurePolicy(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1995)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:102)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:60)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:880)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:216)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.execute(NodeTool.java:184)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:56)
```

nodetool info

```
ERROR 16:22:02,418 Cannot initialize un-mmaper.  (Are you using a non-Oracle JVM?)  Compacted data files will not be removed promptly.  Consider using an Oracle JVM or using standard disk access mode
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'sun.misc.Cleaner sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner()'
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:75) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:880) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:216) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.execute(NodeTool.java:184) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:56) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.10.jar:3.11.10]
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getDiskFailurePolicy(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1995)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:102)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:60)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:880)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:216)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.execute(NodeTool.java:184)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:56)
```

cassandra service status

```
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-03-11 16:02:20 +0630; 20min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3604 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3611 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

မတ် 11 16:02:20 smslb1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured data...
မတ် 11 16:02:20 smslb1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
```

Comment: can you share output of `nodetool status` and `nodetool info` .

Comment: just add please check

Comment: could you please share output of these`ls -ld /var/log/cassandra /var/lib/cassandra` and `nodetool status -h 10.84.36.89`

Comment: have you tried to connect with `cqlsh 10.84.36.89` from server itself.

Comment: ls -ld /var/log/cassandra
drwxr-xr-x 2 cassandra cassandra 4096 မတ်   11 15:41 /var/log/cassandra

ls -ld /var/lib/cassandra
drwxr-xr-x 2 cassandra cassandra 4096 ဇန်   29 18:57 /var/lib/cassandra

"cqlsh 10.84.36.89" already tried this and getting same error

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-on-ubuntu-18-04/
check this link if it helps

Comment: try to start and check if find anything in **system.log**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the errors and symptoms you described, it doesn't look like Cassandra is running.

It's likely that you're not using a supported Java version. You will need to switch to Java 8 with at least update 40 (but newer releases are recommended).

Have a look at the pre-requisites I documented in [Installing Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites) for details. Cheers!

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Thanx buddy working with openjdk version "1.8.0_282"

Comment: Good to hear @KeshavSinha. Cheers!